# App is very slow on receiving data via NSURLConnection's didReceiveData:

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, freeze, lag

I have a problem in my app that I really don't understand.
I have some songs to download in my app when the user wants to have their favorite song available offline. When the download is launched with `NSURLConnection` (even with the `commonRunLoopMode`), my app starts to be very slow, and I can't even scroll a tableView without experiencing freezes.

Why would a simple thing like downloading data make the user experience so bad?

Comment: Are you downloading data async or are you doing it on the main thread?  If you're doing it on the main thread, your UI will become unresponsive.

Comment: It would be more easy if you put the code to set the NSURLConnection, because this can be synchronous or asynchronous, if your are using the first one thats the reason that your app  is experiencing freezes.

Comment: I thought NSURLConnection had to be used on the main thread only. Is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your download code running on the main thread. This thread should be reserved only for short tasks and user interface operations. This is because the user interface is running on this thread so any long running processes on this thread will essentially block the user interface. This is quite a long topic but have a read of this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

and this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

The Grand Central Dispatch will allow you to put any long running process onto a dispatch queue to be processed asynchronously on the background thread.